# Using d3-tip with require js modules

Tags: d3.js, browserify

I've been struggling to get d3-tip to work with browserify. I am getting the following javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

Here is my setup.  package.json has the following dependencies:

```
"d3": "3.5.17"
"d3-tip":"^0.6.7"
```

In my javascript I have:

```
var d3tip = require('d3-tip')(d3);
```

I create a tip:

```
var tip = d3tip();

tip.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
   .offset([-10, 0])
   .html(function(d) {
        return "Hello" ;
    });
```

I then attach the tip show and hide to a bar where the error occurs:

```
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the tip to a selection, eg.

```
var d3tip = require('d3-tip')(d3);

var tip = d3tip();

tip.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
   .offset([-10, 0])
   .html(function(d) {
        return "Hello" ;
    });

var selection = d3.select('.node');

selection
  .call(tip) // <=== here
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseover', tip.hide)
```

Comment: Thanks - thats gets me a little closer but i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.call

Comment: Sorry - my fault - tip was out of scope - got it working